# 10-fold cross validation gets killed

Tags: r, keras

```
k <- 10
folds <- sample(1:k, nrow(X), replace=TRUE)
model_scores <- list()

for(i in 1:k){
  val_indices <- which(folds == i, arr.ind = TRUE)
  x_val <- new_X[val_indices,]
  y_val <- new_Y[val_indices,]
  
  x_train_fold <- new_X[-val_indices,]
  y_train_fold <- new_Y[-val_indices,]
  
  model <- keras_model_sequential()
  
  model %>%
    layer_dense(units = 5000, input_shape = c(4008), activation = "sigmoid") %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 2501, activation = "sigmoid") %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 7, activation = "sigmoid") #7 classes since it is a multi-classification model
  
  model %>% compile(
    optimizer = "adam",
    loss= "bce",
    metrics = list("accuracy")
  )
  
  early_stopping <- callback_early_stopping(
    monitor = "val_loss",
    mode = "min",
    patience = 5,
    restore_best_weights = TRUE
  )
  
  model %>% fit(
    x_train_fold,
    y_train_fold,
    epochs = 1,
    validation_data = list(x_val, y_val),
    callbacks = list(early_stopping)
  )
  
  scores <- model %>% evaluate(x_val, y_val)
  
  prediction <- model %>% predict(x_val)
  print(prediction)
  
}
```

This code is run on R, using tensorflow and keras libraries.
While running this code, it takes almost 3 hours to complete one epoch. Note that I have created one epoch per fold for testing. After the first fold, I get the message
"Killed"

I do not understand why it is getting killed. Can someone explain????

Comment: Usually when I get a process killed, it means I ran out of memory on my machine, so that would be my guess for your case. The typical solution would be to use R's garbage collection `gc()` in your code (or maybe multiple spots). But that won't help if all of the memory consumption happens within the fit function. You could try and put `gc()` before the `fit()` function to see if that helps

Comment: You could try making your model (substantially) smaller. Training a model so large on a laptop CPU is going to be slow, and maybe not possible if there isn't enough memory. ((smaller, narrower but deeper models can work very well too, even better than larger, wider, but shallower models)).

Comment: Also, typically, you'll only  use `sigmoid` as activation on the last layer. Earlier layers you'd typically use "relu" or similar. 

```r
keras_model_sequential(input_shape = 4008) |>  
layer_dense(128, activation = "relu") |>
layer_dense(64, activation = "relu") |> 
 layer_dropout(.5) |> layer_dense(7, activation = "sigmoid")
```